# [powershell]Pasting table from Excel to Word, autofit table

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-word, rpa

Currently working on a robot where I want to download an excel file from a system, copy paste the contents of the excel file to a word file as an embedded excel table, but the table is wider than the page (it is already in landscape mode). I am using a powershell script in DAS to execute this step. To solve the problem normally, I would simply right-click on the table and use Autofit -> Fit to Window. How do I do this in powershell?

My script is currently like this:

```
$word = new-object -comobject Word.application
$word.visible = $true

$doc1 = $word.documents.open($destination)
$bookmark1 = $doc1.Bookmarks.Item("FacilitySheet")

$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $False
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Pater\Downloads\spreadsheet.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.ActiveSheet
$Range1 = $ws.UsedRange.Cells
$RowCount = $Range1.rows.count
$CopyRange = $ws.Range("A1:O$RowCount").Copy()

$bookmark1.Range.Paste()
```

Comment: This is not a powershell problem but rather a feature in the word api. So please check the docs of the Word Api if you can find anything what fits your needs. If there is a function which can handle the autofit, you can call it in the same way as you did with the `Copy()` function.

Comment: Indeed, the solution is as simple as setting the inserted table's preferred width type to % and size to 100 (i.e. 100% of the space between the margins).

Comment: I know it is possible to do this with VBA, but I do not know how do the the proper translation to Powershell:
https://www.groovypost.com/howto/insert-excel-table-into-word-with-vba/

Finally, to deal with Excel ranges that are wider than the document, you’ll need to autofit the new table so it fits within the margins of your new Word document.


Any ideas with that one?

```Set WordTable = WordDoc.Tables(1)
WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this you must set the AutoFitBehavior to the desired value. Please check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.table.autofitbehavior for the allowed values and take into account that the values wdAutoFitContent, etc may not be accessed from Powershell, so you must set the raw values (1 for wdAutoFitContent, for example)

```
$word = new-object -comobject Word.application
$word.visible = $true

$doc1 = $word.documents.open($destination)
$bookmark1 = $doc1.Bookmarks.Item("FacilitySheet")

$xl = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application
$xl.Visible = $true
$xl.DisplayAlerts = $False
$wb = $xl.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Pater\Downloads\spreadsheet.xlsx")
$ws = $wb.ActiveSheet
$Range1 = $ws.UsedRange.Cells
$RowCount = $Range1.rows.count
$CopyRange = $ws.Range("A1:O$RowCount").Copy()

$bookmark1.Range.Paste()
$bookmark1.Range.AutoFitBehavior(1)
```